# How to switch between datasamples in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl, fpga

[image]I have written a code for my I2S interface. this interface has a PISO function (parallel in and serial out). In my testbench, I've added 2 x 24 bits datasamples (left / right channel). Now I would like to switch between this sample and the new second sample (something like: Left1, Right1 , Left2, Right2 , Left1, Right1).

```
elsif rising_edge(BCLK) then
                PDL_BUF <= PDL1;
                PDR_BUF <= PDR1;
                READY   <= '1';
                VALID   <= '1';

                bitcounter := bitcounter + 1;       

                if bitcounter = 1 then
                    WSP <= '1';
                else 
                    WSP <= '0';

                end if;

                if bitcounter >= 0 and bitcounter <= 23 then  
                    WS <= '0';
                elsif bitcounter > 24 then -- and bitcounter <= 48 
                    WS <= '1';
                    WSP <= '0'; 

                end if;

                if WS = '0' then
                    SD <= PDL_BUF(23);
                    PDL_BUF <= PDL_BUF(22 downto 0) & '0';
                else --if WS = '1' then 
                    SD <= PDR_BUF(23);
                    PDR_BUF <= PDR_BUF(22 downto 0) & '0';

                end if;

                if bitcounter = 48 then
                    bitcounter := 0;                

                end if;
        end if;
    end process;
```

Comment: How exactly do you want the samples compare to the clock edges? = is having a channel data every 2 clock cycles what you expect?

Comment: the sample data is 24 bits. The 'sample out' depends on the WS (word select). I've made a bitcounter (48). In this case, the bitcounter is the same as the BCLK. When bitcounter is 48, it get a reset and the new (second sample) can be shifted. So my question is how to shift the second sample.

Comment: right now PDL_BUF is assigned twice on each BCLK, from the PDL1 and from the shift. That can't work, only the shift will be done. I guess you need to load PDL1 only on a given condition, like bitcounter = 0, and then shift from 1 to 49 !?

Comment: It works great as you can see (i've added a picture of my output wave in modelsim). I've tried your suggestion a few days ago, but it doesn't work. That's the reason why i did this on this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a block that is repeated twice for two channels, it is clear that you can't access the other channel in that.

you need to add a block let's call it a merging block.
in merging block consider both samples as input then you can have both of them in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could you maybe give me an example? I'm a newbie in VDHL, so I don't know how to do that  soon. Thanks in advance...